# Override methods while initializating an object

Tags: c#, xna, inheritance

I want to override a method while it's object initialization, something like this:

```
Button = new Button(parameter1, parameter2){
        public override onClicked(){
           //implementation
       }
};
```

This it's what a got:

```
public class Button:Entity
{
    protected Texture2D texture2D;
    public Vector2 vector2; 

    public Button(Texture2D image, Vector2 position
    {
        this.image = image;
        this.position = position;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public abstract void onClicked();

}

abstract class Entity
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public int radius = 20;
    protected Texture2D image;

    public virtual void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(image,position,Color.White);
    }
}
```

I just try to make an implementation like the one I speak before but it does not compile. How one can get this to compile or implement such "per-instance" overrides?

Comment: `OnClicked` (and other `OnSomething` notifications) commonly implemented with [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) - is it what you are looking for?

Comment: It looks you are trying to use a Java-ish syntax, which is not supported by C#.  Your best bet in this case is using something like the solution proposed by Zikronix.

Comment: Yes galenus, i used to do something like this in java and i just thought that C# would support it since it looks pretty similar from Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Button:Entity
{    
  //Vector, Radius and texture are already part of Button, since it extend Entity 
  public EventHandler onClicked;

  public Button(Texture2D image, Vector2 position)
  {
    this.image = image;
    this.position = position;
    this.action = action;
  }
}

abstract class Entity
{
  public Vector2 position;
  public int radius = 20;
  protected Texture2D image;

  public virtual void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
  {
    spriteBatch.Draw(image,position,Color.White);
  }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
Button = new Button(parameter1, parameter2){
   onClicked = new EventHandler(NameOfYourMethod);
};
```